# Verbose preference does not work

Tags: psake

I would like to use the Verbose preference (`$VerbosePreference`) inside my build script. I'm using the *Chocolatey* version of psake (so calling the batch file) and I cannot get it to work well at all.

The `-Verbose` switch works not at all. I ended up adding a property and pass that in. It gets passed in and then I set the `$VerbosePreference` to 'Continue' if it is true, otherwise 'SilentlyContinue'. I created a function to do this. In that function, if I call `Write-Verbose`, it works. However in a task, it does not. If I set the `$VerbosePreference` in the task, it does not work. Basically, I can't use `Write-Verbose` in tasks. What concept am I missing here? Completely flumoxed...